# In iframe if user starts typing (keyboard open) screen got blur in iOS Device

Tags: ios, iframe, input, scroll, keyboard

In iframe, if the user starts typing (keyboard open) screen got blur in iOS Device, it is not visible until unless user scrolls down & focus out the keyboard.
when keyboard press in ios device the iframe position varies, in my code i have written iframe position fixed with 100 vh but due position my ui get distort [image]
[image]

Scnario :In Safari/Chrome in iOS 9.3.2 (I tested on iPhone 6s) clicking button while the input is focused, causes the iFrame to be removed, but the cursor stays blinking on screen. Furthermore, the keyboard stays open (clicking keys does nothing). After dismissing the keyboard, clicking anywhere else in the screen causes the keyboard to pop back again.

Comment: "screen got blur in IOS Device", no idea what you mean? The screenshot does not show any blur apart from the blurred keyboard background.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue got solved by body
 html {height:100%; overflow-x:hidden }
may be it will help others